# Filtering by specific value incorrectly returns no results

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Dynamics CRM 2011 on premise.

We have customised the incident/case entity to add new fields and customised the views for this entity to show some of the new fields. One of the fields is a reference to another entity (Benefit in this screenshot:
[image]

When I enable filters I get these options:
[image]

All options work apart from "Filter by specific Benefit...".

Selecting this option shows this screen:
[image]

No matter what is selected, the resulting list is empty, even when it shouldn't be. No error is shown.

The behaviour is the same in the latest IE and latest Chrome.

How can I investigate this?

Comment: just tested and on my system and the filter works. Did you press "Add" after you selected the records and before press "Ok"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filter isn't applied by value, but by reference.  You have multiple benefits with the same name, but are actually different entities.  Therefore, if you "select Dental", it won't filter to all "Dental" records, but just filter to incidents/cases for that particular "Dental" record as a benefit.

If you wanted to see only those that were Dental or Hospital, or Optical, you'd need to add an Option Set to your incident/case entity that basically is the name of the Benefit record assigned.

Comment: good catch Daryl, in fact inside the last picture is visible the top part of another record called "Dental"

Comment: @GuidoPreite I did notice that as well, but the 5000+ records is what gave it away for me that these weren't unique by name.

Comment: Wow that's so obvious now. Shocked that that wasn't obvious to me. Thank you.